# How to install Gears in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

With Ubuntu 10.10 Lucid and its default Firefox 3.6.13, when I follow the normal installation procedure of Google Gears I receive this error:

> "Google Gears" could not be installed
>   because it is not compatible with your
>   Firefox build type (Linux_x86-gcc3)

[image]

How can I install Gears on the latest Ubuntu with default Firefox?

Comment: "On February 19, 2010, the Gears team at Google announced that the development of Google Gears had stopped, as they are working on bringing all of the Gears capabilities into web standards like HTML5". what site that you are using requires gears?

Comment: @Alaukik: Gmail offline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WRONG: Head to the Google Gears site over [here](http://gears.google.com/), then just follow the instructions. Please note that right now, Google Gears is being deprecated to make way for a newer, more powerful tool.

**EDIT:** After having the question clarified and expanded some more, I have a solution. Install Google Gears from [here](http://gears64.org/files/build/0.5.34.0/3417/gears-linux-opt-0.5.34.0.xpi) (It's a direct download), and enjoy. Worked for me on Ubuntu 10.10 and Firefox 3.6.13. [image]

Comment: As you can see on the screenshot, it does not work. Which versions of Ubuntu/Firefox are you using?

Comment: I had installed it previously. I've got an edit coming in a moment.

Comment: Thanks, the EDIT section works, Gmail offline runs fine :-) Minor annoyance: Every couple of hours, the same popup appears, saying: "Google Gears" could not be installed because it is not compatible with your Firefox build type (Linux_x86-gcc3). Please contact the author of this item about the problem.

Comment: Odd. I'll contact them with that. And the answer below me is worth a look at as well.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Jrgifford maybe nice for this XPI. But I want to share with you and other people the following solution for all the XPI's with compatible problem:

Editing an add-on to change its compatibility

See link: 
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_an_add-on_to_change_its_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

On Lucid, there is a gears package in the archive.  We removed it from Maverick since gears is dead upstream.